# create name for both header and column but type once

Tags: excel

I am trying to set up a collection of spreadsheets for others to use.  I am putting labels on the first row for each column, I think of them as headers in that case.  And I know how to name a column in Excel (at least 2010 lets you do this).

If I have columns with the headers "higher" and "lower", and the columns have those names also, then the formula "=higher+lower" in a given row would use the values from those columns in that row to calculate the result.

I would like to end up with the descriptive column name being the same as the header value.  I'd like a way to either create the headers from the column names, or create the column names from the headers, so I don't have to enter them twice.  I have a lot of columns, and multiple spreadsheets to do this with; I'm just trying to save typing them all twice, and both initially and to keep them updated as they change.

Comment: Are you looking for code? What have you tried?

Comment: I suppose I'll entertain a VBA solution if that's all there is.  I have searched through options for either how to name the column based on the cell, or a formula to display the descriptive name of the column in the cell, but haven't found anything.  In my experience, there are lots and lots and lots of options in Excel that one has never heard of, am hoping there is something in that line that will do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually: Select the desired columns and go Formulas Ribbon > Create from Selection, tick "Top row" and hit OK. Repeat when you've changed a value in row 1.

With VBA: Use this code in the worksheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Range("1:1"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    For Each cel In Target
        Debug.Print cel.Column
        Columns(cel.Column).Select
        Selection.CreateNames Top:=True, Left:=False, Bottom:=False, Right:=False
        cel.Select
    Next cel
End If
End Sub
```

If you copy and paste the same value into multiple cells, Excel will create the first name and then prompt for the other cells if you want to replace the existing name.

Changing a cell in row 1 will create a new range name. The old range name will still remain in place.

If you have values that can be interpreted as a cell address, like `A1`, Excel will add a _ sign to the range name, like `A1_`. If you enter numbers into row 1, Excel won't create range names.

Comment: The power of StackOverflow -- from the US to NZ and back in 30 minutes, exactly what I was looking for.  I'd upvote it twice if I could.  Thanks.